# why cant i use all the font awewsome icons locally?

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-awesome

Why cant i use all the font awesome icons offline ?

i can use a car

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fontawesome-free-5.13.1-web\css\all.css">  

</head>
 <body>

<i class="fa fa-car"></i>

 </body>
</html>
```

but i cant use a light bulb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fontawesome-free-5.13.1-web\css\all.css">  

</head>
 <body>

<i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>

 </body>
</html>
```

There is nothing wrong with the file path.

i downloaded free package from fontawesome.com , started using icons . Some of icons i can use but some i cant. I did not downloaded anything extra.

Do i need to download the icons i cant use individually . if so how?

Comment: Are you trying to use the `lightbuld-on` icon? For one, you're not spelling it right. But also it's not free, it's part of the pro package. If you want to use one of the free lightbulb icons: https://fontawesome.com/icons/lightbulb?style=solid or https://fontawesome.com/icons/lightbulb?style=regular

Comment: if it is in pro package then why it is so that i can use it when i use the  reference code provided by the font awesome  in html link tag.